# What is the difference between StringIO and io.StringIO in Python2.7?

Tags: python, string

Besides the obvious (one is a type, the other a class)? What should be preferred? Any notable difference in use cases, perhaps?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/library/io.html#io.StringIO

http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html

I see this.

> An in-memory stream for unicode text. It inherits TextIOWrapper.
>
> This module implements a file-like class, StringIO, that reads and writes a string buffer (also known as memory files).

`io.StringIO` is a class.  It handles Unicode.  It reflects the preferred Python 3 library structure.

`StringIO.StringIO` is a class.  It handles strings.  It reflects the legacy Python 2 library structure.

> What should be preferred?

Always move forward toward the new library organization.  The `io.open` should be used to replace the built-in Unicode-unaware `open`.

Forward.  Move forward.

Comment: Actually, moving forward to io.StringIO behavior can cause problems if your other 2.7 packages/modules are not yet unicode-aware. At least it did for me when gunicorn "moved forward" and Django did not [here](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/pull/728/files) and [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20185).

Comment: @hobs I hit the same problem trying to use io.StringIO to mock.patch `argparse`. The best way I found to make tests run in both 2 and 3 was `try: from StringIO import StringIO except ImportError: from io import StringIO`.

Answer (score 6):

In terms of python 2.7 and 3:

`io.BytesIO` is an in-memory file-like object that *doesn't* do any alteration to newlines, and is similar to `open(filename, "wb")`. It deal with `bytes()` strings, which in py2.7 is an alias for `str`.

`io.StringIO` is an in-memory file-like object that *does* do alterations to newlines, and is similar to `open(filename, "w")`. It deal with `unicode()` strings, which in py3.x is an alias for `str`.

py2.7's old `StringIO.StringIO` is an in-memory file-like object that *does not* do alterations to newlines, and is similar to `open(filename, "w")`. It deals with both `unicode()` and `bytes()` in the same way that most obsolete python 2 string methods do: by allowing you to mix them without error, but only as long as you're lucky.

Thus py2.7's old `StringIO.StringIO` class is actually more similar to `io.BytesIO` than `io.StringIO`, as it is operating in terms of `bytes()`/`str()` and *doesn't* do newline conversions.

> What should be preferred?

Don't use `StringIO.StringIO`, instead use `io.BytesIO` or `io.StringIO`, depending on the use-case. This is forward compatible with python 3 and commits to bytes or unicode, rather than "both, maybe".

Comment: This actually solved a problem I was having: "It deal with bytes() strings, which in py2.7 is an alias for str." Eureka! I was passing python 2 `StringIO` to the traceback.print_stack() function, and when updating it to be Python3 compatable. `is.StringIO` didnt work. But io.BytesIO did!